# Error in drop/select query for phoenix table to access hbase table

Tags: mysql, jdbc, hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I created a table (MyTable) in hbase and added data to it and then tried to access through phoenix client.

I got an exception due to query bug while creating virtual table with the same name (MyTable). I then found that the table got created even though an exception occurred.

Could not access, alter, or drop MyTable.  I get following:

```
0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost> drop table "MyTable";
Error: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: ubi_stream_realtime: 109 (state=08000,code=101)

0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost> select * from "MyTable";
Error: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: ubi_stream_realtime: 109 (state=08000,code=101)

0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost> !dropall
Really drop every table in the database? (y/n)abort-drop-all: Aborting drop all tables.y
Error: ERROR 1012 (42M03): Table undefined. tableName=MyTable (state=42M03,code=1012)
Aborting command set because "force" is false and command failed: "DROP TABLE MyTable;"
```

I tried following ways but could not delete the phoenix mapping.

- Drop table in hbase and tried all queries in phoenix
- Tried rename query in phoenix
- restarted hbase and as well as phoenix client
- recreated same table in phoenix as well as in hbase